# Save shortest path in a "structured file" using networkx and osmnx

Tags: networkx, osmnx

I have a multidimensional graph `G` and a list `best_path` calculated using the method [`nx.shortest_path`](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html).

Thanks to this [stackexchange post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166515/networkx-saving-shortest-path-of-openstreetmap-data-as-an-ogr-friendly-format), I am exporting the x and y coordinates of my route in a simple ascii file using `json.dumps`:

```py
parts = []
for i in best_path:
    node = G.nodes[i]
    parts.append([float(node["y"]), float(node["x"])])
json_route = json.dumps(parts)

with open(current_dir + "test_best_path.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(parts, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Now I am looking for a solution where I could savethis best route into a more "structured" file where I could also add more node attributes (e.g. yaml or graphml). Does something already exist in `networkx` or `osmnx`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create the induced subgraph of your path, i.e.,

```
shortest_path_graph = G.subgraph(best_path) #.copy()
```

and may create a copy, if you want to perform changes, which should not be reflected in the original graph.

Then you can apply any changes and add any changes to `shortest_path_graph`, e.g., add node attributes, or remove existing not needed information. Afterwards, you can save your result using any of `networkx` [save methods](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/index.html), e.g., [`GraphML`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/graphml.html) or [`YAML`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/yaml.html) to follow your proposals. I would highly recommend to avoid pickle, if you want to share the file between different PCs.

#### Edit

As the above process will loose the information about the node order in the path or in other words, I would expect the above procedure returns a line, i.e., in the directed case one node with out degree 1 and in degree 0, another node with in degree 1 and out degree 0, and all other nodes in degree = 1 = out degree.

For saving the order of the nodes in the path, you can either create a new attribute

```
for i, node in enumerate(best_path):
    shortest_path_graph.nodes[node]["path counter"] = i
```

or use [`nx.relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html#networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes) to modify the node ids.

#### Edit 2 - from @lhoupert

I like the solution with nx.relabel_nodes which doesn't create a new attribute.
An example of implementation can be seen below:

```py
# Relabel nodes id to sort them according to the path orientation 
mapping_dict = {num: x for x,num in enumerate(best_path)} 
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G_shortest_path, mapping_dict) 

# Sort the graph nodes and edges according to new ID  
H2 = nx.Graph()  # or nx.MultiDiGraph()
H2.add_nodes_from(sorted(H.nodes(data=True)))  
H2.add_edges_from(H.edges(data=True))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. It worked well, I didn't know about the `.subgraph()` method... Do you know if when exporting a file the node and each are listed in the order corresponding to the shortest path (from the starting point to the end point)?

Comment: The order will probably only be implicitly preserved by the degree of the nodes. If you explicitly want to store it, you need to add this information. I've extended my answer to cover this.

Comment: Thank you. I like your solution with `nx.relabel_nodes` which doesn't create a new attribute. My implementation can be seen below: 
```python 
# Relabel nodes id to sort them according to the path orientation  \
mapping_dict = {num: x for x,num in enumerate(best_path)}  \
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G_shortest_path, mapping_dict)  \
\
# Sort the graph nodes and edges according to new ID  \
H2 = nx.Graph()  \
H2.add_nodes_from(sorted(H.nodes(data=True)))  \
H2.add_edges_from(H.edges(data=True))  \
```

Comment: You can edit my answer and include your code, which is then probably easier to read than in the comment :)